# I'm really confused with the pointer

Tags: c, pointers

in scanf("%d",ptr->age) why do I need to add an & in front of ptr->age since char(ptr->gender) is not adding an &?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5

struct person
{
char name[7];
char gender[3];
int age;
};

void input_by_adress(struct person *ptr);
void output_by_value(struct person shopper);

int main()
{

struct person buyer;
input_by_adress (&buyer);
printf("\n>> shopper info: ");
output_by_value(buyer);
return 0;
} 

void input_by_adress(struct person *ptr)
{
printf("name? ");
scanf("%s", ptr->name);
printf("gender? ");
scanf("%s", ptr->gender);
printf("age? ");
scanf("%d", &ptr->age);

}

void output_by_value(struct person shopper)
{
printf("%s(%s) %d세", shopper.name, shopper.gender, shopper.age);

}
```

this is the code for clarifying if it is call by adress ot call by value
and the part i am wondering is    scanf("%d", &ptr->age);

Comment: What is `ptr`, `gender`, `age`, etc? What `&`? Please provide complete code as a [mre].

Comment: At a guess `gender` is an array. The name of an array is also a pointer already so don't need `&`.

Comment: I edited my example; this is my first question and sorry for that.

Comment: As guessed, `gender` is an array which already decays to a pointer. See the duplicate post for more details.